# Why cant I interact with my google docs embedded in my google site?

Tags: google-docs, google-sites

Happy Friday!

So, a while ago, I embedded a Google docs folder in my Google site.  What a great feature!
But here is the problem:  when I first embedded it, when I clicked on an embedded folder, there would be a section on the left, in which, I could, from the site, add files.  All I had to do was just drag and drop them into the folder embedded on the website itself.  Now, that option is just not there!

Have I changed some sort of setting by accident?  Did Google change the way the embedding operates to disallow this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same OS and same web browser as before? It is doing anything strange like downloading the file when you drag and drop it?

Comment: Thanks for asking for that clarification.  Same browser (Chrome) and same OS (Windows 7).  Before, there was actually a button you clicked when wishing to add a file.  That button is no longer there.  Just to try I tried to drag and drop a file to the image of the folder anyway, but it just downloaded it to my downloaded documents folder on my local drive.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I tried it, and it did not work for what you were wanting. I don't see the option anywhere, unfortunately. I did look around, and it seems you may be able to use the old method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites), but I'm not sure if it would still work, but I assume so. It could always be a thing to try.

Comment: Well, thank you so much for taking the time... Much appreciated. Have a great day!

Comment: No problem! If you do try the old method, I am curious to know if it does work.

Comment: Will do, I will most likely give it a shot on Monday.  Will let you know.

Comment: So the older method allowed you to do what you were wanting?

Comment: yes.  It was not as pretty from a UI perspective, but worked.  I would still like to know if the design of the embedded folders is SUPPOSED to allow for manipulation of folders (adding documents) or not.